# Insert Images into an Excel File (Flutter Framework)

Tags: flutter, dart, export-to-excel

### Excel

I am using the excel package to create an Excel file. My problem is that I can't insert images into an Excel file. How can I insert images or any type of binary data?

My excel file contains 4 columns :

- Name
- Image
- UOM
- Price
- Barcode

I developed code to export an Excel file.

```
void startExportCategoriesExcel(List<ExportParams> ExportParams,
      CustomerModel customerModel, String accountBase64, bool share) async {
    if (ExportParams.isEmpty) {
      showToast(Trans.noDataToExport.trans());
      return;
    }

    try {
      showLoadingProgressAlert();

      final String sheetName = "Category-PAR-${Random().nextInt(10000)}";
      final excel = Excel.createExcel();
      excel.rename('Sheet1', sheetName);
      final Sheet sheetObject = excel[sheetName];

      List<List<dynamic>> excelExport = [];
      // excelExport = [
      //   [customerModel.customerName,
      //   customerModel.phoneNo ?? '',
      //   ]
      // ];

      excelExport.add([
        "#",
        Trans.image.trans(),
        Trans.name.trans(),
        Trans.uom.trans(),
        Trans.price.trans(),
        Trans.barcode.trans(),
      ]);

      int index = 0;
      for (var element in ExportParams) {
        index++;

        // Load the image from the network using http package
        img.Image? image;
        try {
          var response = await Dio().get(element.image,
              options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
          if (response.statusCode != 200) {
            logger('Failed to load image: ${response.statusCode}');
          }

          image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(response.data));
        } catch (e) {
          image = null;
        }

        final barcodeImage = img.Image(width: 300, height: 50);
        img.fill(barcodeImage, color: img.ColorRgb8(255, 255, 255));
        drawBarcode(
          barcodeImage,
          Barcode.code128(),
          element.barcode ?? "",
        );

        // var excelImage = ExcelImage(image);

        excelExport.add([
          "$index",
          image != null
              ? image.buffer.asUint8List()
              : image ?? '', //element.image,
          element.name,
          element.prices.isEmpty ? '-' : element.prices.first.uom,
          element.prices.isEmpty ? '-' : element.prices.first.price,
          barcodeImage.buffer.asUint8List(), //element.barcode ?? '',
        ]);
      }

      for (var element in excelExport) {
        sheetObject.appendRow(element);
      }
      List<int>? data4 = excel.encode();
      if (data4 == null) {
        failedAlert(error: Trans.operationFalied.trans());
        return;
      }

      Directory? downloadsDirectory;
      if (kIsWeb != true) {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          // downloadsDirectory = await DownloadsPath.downloadsDirectory();
          downloadsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        } else {
          downloadsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        }
        if (downloadsDirectory == null) {
          failedAlert(error: Trans.operationFalied.trans());
          return;
        }
        final String path = downloadsDirectory.path;
        final dir = await Directory(path).create(recursive: true);
        final fullPath =
            "${dir.path}/${Trans.priceList.trans()} ${DateTime.now().toString().split(".")[0].replaceAll(":", "-")}.xlsx";
        File file = File((fullPath));

        if (await file.exists()) {
          await file.delete();
        }
        file
          ..createSync(recursive: true)
          ..writeAsBytesSync(data4);

        Helper.i.pop();
        Helper.i.pop();
        if (!share) {
          openFileAlert(path: fullPath);
        } else {
          Share.shareXFiles([XFile(fullPath)]);
        }
      } else {
        MimeType type = MimeType.microsoftExcel;
        await FileSaver.instance.saveFile(
            name:
                "${Trans.accountStatments.trans()} ${DateTime.now().toString().split(".")[0].replaceAll(":", "-")}",
            bytes: Uint8List.fromList(data4),
            ext: "xlsx",
            mimeType: type);
        Helper.i.pop();
        Helper.i.pop();
      }
    } catch (e, c) {
      recoredError(e, c);
      logger(e);
      Helper.i.pop();
      Helper.i.pop();
      Helper.i.pop();
      failedAlert(error: Trans.operationFalied.trans());
    }
  }
```

- I don't want commercial packages to add some images to my excel file. !!!

Comment: Did you find a way to do this without commercial packages?

Answer (score 0):

[Excel Package](https://pub.dev/packages/excel) currently has no image/video adding feature. As the developer of the package says it's complicated and time-consuming progress. [Here](https://github.com/justkawal/excel/issues/45) you can see the open issue.

Instead, I suggest you to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio . It offers image adding feature. Here is the example;

```
// Create a new Excel document.
final Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
//Accessing worksheet via index.
final Worksheet sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];

//Adding a picture
final List<int> bytes = File('image.png').readAsBytesSync();
final Picture picture = sheet.picutes.addStream(1, 1, bytes);

// Save the document.
final List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
File('AddingImage.xlsx').writeAsBytes(bytes);
//Dispose the workbook.
workbook.dispose();
```

Good luck.